# Existence and uniqueness theorem applying the Runge-Kutta formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I want prove that the problem

$$y'=f(x,y)$$
$$y(x_0)=y_0$$

It has a unique solution if $f$ is continuous in $[a,b] \times \mathbb{R}^n$ and it satisfies the Lipschitz condition with respect to the second variable. Applying the Runge-Kutta formula of order 4

**My attempt**

Finding the solution of the problem is equivalent to finding the solution of

$$y(x)=y_0+\int_{x_0}^{x}f(t,y(t))dt$$

By applying the Runge-Kutta method of order 4, we obtain the sequence $\left\{y_n\right\}$ given by

$$y_n=y_{n-1}+\dfrac{\Delta x}{6}\left(k_1+2k_2+2k_3+k_4\right)$$

where

$$k_1=f\left(x_0+\Delta x (n-1),y_{n-1}\right)$$
$$k_2=f\left(x_0+\Delta x (n-1) +\dfrac{\Delta x}{2},y_{n-1}+\dfrac{k_1 \Delta x}{2}\right) $$
$$k_3=f\left(x_0+\Delta x (n-1) +\dfrac{\Delta x}{2},y_{n-1}+\dfrac{k_2 \Delta x}{2}\right) $$
$$k_4=f\left(x_0 + n \Delta x, y_{n-1}+k_3 \Delta x\right)$$

It's easy to see that

$$y_n=y_0+ \sum_{m=1}^n \left(y_m-y_{m-1}\right)$$

The sequence $\left\{y_n\right\}$ is convergent in $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if the series

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(y_m-y_{m-1}\right)$$

is convergent.

Let's prove that the series is uniformly convergent in $[a,b]$ for this we will apply the Weierstrass test $M$, for this we must prove that there exist $M_m>0$ such that

$$|y_m-y_{m-1}| \leq M_m \quad \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}M_m < \infty$$

Let's first find $M_1$ and $M_2$ to be able to establish a recursion for the $M_m$ this is

$$|y_1-y_0| \leq M_1 \quad |y_2-y_1| \leq M_2$$

However

$$y_1=y_{0}+\dfrac{\Delta x}{6}\left(k_{11}+2k_{21}+2k_{31}+k_{41}\right)$$

where

$$k_{11}=f\left(x_0,y_{0}\right)$$
$$k_{21}=f\left(x_0 +\dfrac{\Delta x}{2},y_{0}+\dfrac{k_{11} \Delta x}{2}\right) $$
$$k_{31}=f\left(x_0 +\dfrac{\Delta x}{2},y_{0}+\dfrac{k_{21} \Delta x}{2}\right) $$
$$k_{41}=f\left(x_0 + \Delta x, y_{0}+k_{31} \Delta x\right)$$

and

$$y_2=y_{1}+\dfrac{\Delta x}{6}\left(k_{12}+2k_{22}+2k_{32}+k_{42}\right)$$

where

$$k_{12}=f\left(x_0+\Delta x ,y_{1}\right)$$
$$k_{22}=f\left(x_0 +\dfrac{ 3 \Delta x}{2},y_{1}+\dfrac{k_{12} \Delta x}{2}\right) $$
$$k_{32}=f\left(x_0 +\dfrac{3 \Delta x}{2},y_{1}+\dfrac{k_{22} \Delta x}{2}\right) $$
$$k_{41}=f\left(x_0 + 2 \Delta x, y_{1}+k_{32} \Delta x\right)$$

Therefore

$$|y_1-y_0| =\left| \dfrac{\Delta x}{6}\left(k_{11}+2k_{21}+2k_{31}+k_{41}\right) \right|$$

and

$$|y_2-y_1| = \left|\dfrac{\Delta x}{6}\left(k_{12}+2k_{22}+2k_{32}+k_{42}\right) \right|$$

Is my procedure correct? How can I continue?

Comment: If you want to bound the $y$ you’ll likely need to use the Lipschitz bound on $f$

Comment: What is the motivation of this question? Do you want to replace the Picard iteration with the RK4 method with step size converging to 0? Usually it is the other way round, one takes an existing solution and proves that the RK method converges towards it. Please add more details surrounding this task.

Comment: Yes, I want to replace the Picard iteration with the RK4 with convergent step to 0.

Comment: Why do I have the impression that this is AI generated? A mindless, superficially coherent mashup of related but distinct topics. If that is the case, please desist, as it is against policy. If that is not the case, please add more details on the outer frame of this question and your own approaches towards it solution. That telescoping sums are telescoping and copy-paste of the RK4 steps are not sufficient.